# Why does span style=cursor:help give so many problems?

Tags: html, css, styles

I try to use this function for a word-view function at my website, but for some reason it works at the normal text, but stops working when I use a special font. I also had another website where it stopped working when it was applied to another style-element, why is it that this function stops working in other styles?

When I started using this:

```
@font-face {
font-family:gothicw;src:url('gothic1.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

it stopped working, also all other ways to write @font-face make it stop working.

Comment: Please paste in some code examples, it will be great for answering.

Comment: No need anymore, as you see in my own answer I solved the problem with removing one small part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I used 'preg_replace' twice, while I replaced a text with "cursor:help" in one part of my code, this is why it stopped working, because another part of my code used preg_replace again, which eliminated the effect of the previous one. I hope this helps anyone with the same problem with cursor:help.